# LF RFID signal jammers

Tags: rf, rfid

I am currently researching into the security of RFID based access control in relation with jammers. For an experiment, I am trying to build a device that can jam 125 kHz RFID cards from like a meter away. I have found products on the internet that can do so passively up to 1cm of distance.

What kind of antenna/technology would I need to achieve lets say 20cm or 50cm or even 1 meter of distance with such a device? It's just for the experiment which is stationary, so input power is not a problem as it does not have to be portable. I also have the receiver on a fixed position, so a directional antenna for more power can be used.

The problem that I faced is that my understading is that the antenna has to have a length of wavelength / 2, which for 125kHz would be well over 2km, which obviously cannot be built. Am I missing something here?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The long ferrite rods in old AM radios may be of use in focusing the Magnetic field.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, I have some laying arounds somewhere I'm going to try this

Answer (score 0):

at the scales involved the 125 KHz signale are basically magnetic fields, so to disrupt a card from 1m away you need to make a stronger 125KHz magnetic field in the proximity of the card than the card is making (or the same sort of signal level at-least), that's probably going to require large coils and strong currents.

Comment: Ok, so it's not actually RF that can be interrupted?